# Remove white border around font awesome icon

Tags: html, css, sass, font-awesome

I've been trying to hack the font awesome icon to be all the blue with the icon white but this is the closest I've been. Know what I need to add/remove? Tried transparent borders, remove padding/margins, positioned absoluted a span behind with no luck.

[image]

```css
 

   .b-social-media-shares__a {
        width: 48px;
        height: 48px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0 6px;

        &:hover {
            box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px grey;
        }

        i {
            color: white;
            line-height: 48px;
            font-size: 25px;
        }


    }
    .b-social-media-shares--facebook {
      background-color: #4267B2;
    }

    .b-social-media-shares--facebook .fa-facebook-f {
      color: #4267B2;
      line-height: 48px;
      font-size: 28px;
    }

    .b-social-media-shares--facebook .fa-facebook-f:before {
      content: "\f09a";
      background-color: white;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }

    .b-social-media-shares--facebook:hover {
      background-color: white;
    }

    .b-social-media-shares--facebook:hover i {
      color: #4267B2;
    }
```

```html
<a id="facebook" href="" class="b-social-media-shares__a b-social-media-shares--facebook dnt" target="_blank">
  <i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some unnecessary and some conflicting styles. See comments in the code:

```
.b-social-media-shares__a {
  display: inline-flex; // added
  align-items: center; // added
  justify-content: center; // added
  text-decoration: none; // added, but not required (removes the underline)

  width: 48px;
  height: 48px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  // text-align: center; // not required because of `justify-content`
  margin: 0 6px;

  &:hover {
    box-shadow: 1px 3px 5px grey;
  }

  i {
    color: white;
    // line-height: 48px; // not really required
    font-size: 25px;
  }
}
.b-social-media-shares--facebook {
  background-color: #4267b2;
}

.b-social-media-shares--facebook .fa-facebook-f {
  // color: #4267b2; // not required (it should be white)
  // line-height: 48px; // not really required
  font-size: 28px;
}

// This whole ruleset is not required
// .b-social-media-shares--facebook .fa-facebook-f:before {
//   content: "\f09a";
//   background-color: white;
//   border-radius: 50%;
// }

.b-social-media-shares--facebook:hover {
  background-color: white;
}

.b-social-media-shares--facebook:hover i {
  color: #4267b2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe as an alternate solution you could place just the "f" in a blue circle

I made this snippet, I hope it helps:

https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-dust-2vfvi?file=/src/index.js:69-132

Comment: Looks good on test but .fa-facebook-f {
  color: white;
}
the whole circle becomes white on mine

Comment: @MPortman did you change the icon from "fab fa-facebook" to "fab fa-facebook-f" ? Keep in mind you are using the whole circle with the f and you need to use just the "f" icon:

https://fontawesome.com/icons/facebook-f?style=brands

Answer (score 0):

There is no border... You're putting a circle icon inside a circular element that's larger than the icon. The wrapper element has a white background and a blue border. This background is showing behind your icon.

Change

```
.b-social-media-shares--facebook .fa-facebook-f:before {
      background-color: white;
    }
```

to have a blue background...

Comment: Then the whole circle and icon is the blue. The idea is to have the 'f' be white which is where the background-color comes but it spills out of the icon.

Comment: Then use the version without the circle... https://fontawesome.com/v4.7.0/icon/facebook and make your own background